# Selected text fades away in a 640px or less viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that if you click one of the boxes shown in my snippet, a checkmark shows up and the content inside of shows as if it is active after you move the mouse away from it. However, when viewed with a viewport of 640px or less, the text inside of the boxes fades away after you select it and select something else. It is not doing this in a normal desktop view, so why is it doing it withing that specific media query? I did not make any changes to my `.box-focused` css in the media query at all, nor did I even include it because I wanted everything the same.

Does anyone see what it is that is causing this to happen?

```js
$('.project-option-boxes').click(function() {
  $(this).hide().toggleClass('box_focused').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
#project-scope-container {
 margin-top: 70px;
 margin-left: 9%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 300px;
}
.project-option-boxes {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0px;
 margin: 12px 20px 12px 0px;
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.project-option-boxes:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.box_focused {
  background-color: #45ba95;
  color: #FFF;
  background-image : url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/white_checkmark.png");
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 5% 50%; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .project-option-boxes {
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0px;
 margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
 width: 85%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.project-option-boxes:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
}
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-scope-container">
  <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DESIGN</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">ECOMMERCE</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but `box-focused` has a color of `#FFF`, so that should make the content the white like it does on the desktop view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the colours correctly for the focused styles in the media query. See my addition of the `box_focused` class to the media query below.

```js
$('.project-option-boxes').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().toggleClass('box_focused').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
#project-scope-container {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 9%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 300px;
}

.project-option-boxes {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #45ba95;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin: 12px 20px 12px 0px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #45ba95;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.project-option-boxes:hover {
    background-color: #45ba95;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.box_focused {
    background-color: #45ba95;
    color: #FFF;
    background-image : url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/white_checkmark.png");
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 5% 50%; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    .project-option-boxes {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #45ba95;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
        width: 85%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: #45ba95;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .project-option-boxes:hover, .box_focused {
        background-color: #45ba95;
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-scope-container">
    <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DESIGN</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">ECOMMERCE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you are saying to add `box-focused` to my media query?

Comment: Yes, it just needs the same styles as .project-option-boxes:hover does in the media query.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I didn't think I would need to put it in their again since I had it in my normal css part.

Comment: dang, he beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the same css settings copied into the media query for the same to apply. its because the scope limits what code is read

```js
$('.project-option-boxes').click(function() {
  $(this).hide().toggleClass('box_focused').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
#project-scope-container {
 margin-top: 70px;
 margin-left: 9%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 300px;
}
.project-option-boxes {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0px;
 margin: 12px 20px 12px 0px;
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.project-option-boxes:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.box_focused {
  background-color: #45ba95;
  color: #FFF;
  background-image : url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/white_checkmark.png");
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 5% 50%; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .project-option-boxes {
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0px;
 margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
 width: 85%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.project-option-boxes:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
  .box_focused {
  background-color: #45ba95;
  color: #FFF;
  background-image : url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/white_checkmark.png");
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 5% 50%; 
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-scope-container">
  <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DESIGN</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
  <div class="project-option-boxes">ECOMMERCE</div>
 </div>
```